# New magento trial account algolia, run through 100.000 operations in 1 day with 300 products

Tags: magento, search, algolia

With great enthousiasm i installed the Magento extension in a store having issues with its search. it worked amazing for me within minutes search results came back superb.

Its a small store, with around 100 unique visitors a day and 300 unique products. Within a day i received notifications about running to 50 and 80% of my trial amount of 100.000 operations.

only a few minutes later it reached 100.000+.

These are the stats

```
 Delete Record 67 %
 Update Record 33 %
 Query 0.17 %
 Set Settings 0.04 %
 Get Settings 0.01 %
```

With a lot of these lines:

```
/1/indexes/magento_default_products/batch
/1/indexes/magento_default_products/batch
/1/indexes/magento_default_products/batch
/1/indexes/magento_default_products/batch
/1/indexes/magento_default_products/batch
/1/indexes/magento_default_products/batch
```

Whats going on, i checked all settings and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The extension is following changes of the magento instance to have the index up to date.
- When a product is saved in the db it will trigger an operation to update it in Algolia. same for creation/deletion
- Same for categories.

When magento products are updated by a third party service importer, depending on the implementation it can generate a lot of operations.

You should contact support at algolia dot com for more details

Comment: Yes i did that indeed. There is a stock updater running very frequent. but this should not trigger the sync right. is there a way to limit the sync to 4times a day or somethign